# curl error 35, possible reasons?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

The trouble showed itself yesterday - getting following answer from curl (called in php script by curl_exec):

```
$<errno>35</errno>
$<error>Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to w3s.webmoney.ru:443 </error>
```

That bug happens only sometimes, something around 4-5 valid responses to one invalid with 35 error. Before yesterday application was handling those requests correctly for a very long time.

Hope someone will give me a hint about possible reasons of that bug.

P.S. We are suffering from internet connection problems lately, can it be somehow connected to that bug?

**Upd:**
Setting verbose output to true made curl to write following log:

```
* About to connect() to w3s.webmoney.ru port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 82.198.171.158... * connected
* Connected to w3s.webmoney.ru (82.198.171.158) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ${path}/WebMoneyCA.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using RC4-MD5
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=RU; O=WebMoney Transfer; OU=WebMoney Web Service; CN=w3s.webmoney.ru
*        start date: 2010-06-07 10:03:43 GMT
*        expire date: 2012-06-07 10:13:43 GMT
*        common name: w3s.webmoney.ru (matched)
*        issuer: OU=WM Transfer Certification Services; O=WM Transfer Ltd; CN=WebMoney Transfer Root CA
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /asp/XMLPurses.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: w3s.webmoney.ru
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 281
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 10 Dec 2010 13:00:04 GMT
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Content-Length: 4423
< Content-Type: text/xml; Charset=windows-1251
< Expires: Fri, 10 Dec 2010 13:00:04 GMT
< Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDQADQDTAQ=FJMNECHBENFFAADHEHPFOKAE; path=/
< Cache-control: private
<
* Connection #0 to host w3s.webmoney.ru left intact
* Closing connection #0
* About to connect() to w3s.webmoney.ru port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 212.158.173.158... * connected
* Connected to w3s.webmoney.ru (212.158.173.158) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ${path}/WebMoneyCA.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to w3s.webmoney.ru:443
* Closing connection #0
```

**Upd**: 
The trouble was not on our side. The problem was hidden somewhere in w3s.webmoney.ru, in 212.158.173.158 server. I'll add more details about the bug if information will be available.

Comment: Try setting CURLOPT_VERBOSE to true and adding the log to this question. Error 35 means something went wrong during the SSL/TLS handshake and could be caused by a lot of things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the following response from WM support people:

"There are four IP addresses on hostname w3s.webmoney.ru. When a request ends up on 212.158.173.158, SSL is getting killed by a piece of anti-DDoS hardware at the provider's. The problem was localized, they're now trying to fix it."

Comment: I got less informative answer than yours: support simply said that they are aware of the problem and recommended to send requests to any other ip address.

Comment: @n0weak: haven't seen the error in a while. Guess they've fixed it finally.